# Compare Calculation-time for two methods

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

Method $1$ (Machin): 
$$
\pi = 16 \left(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{3\cdot 5^3} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 5^5} - \frac{1}{7\cdot 5^7} + \ldots\right) -4\left(\frac{1}{239} - \frac{1}{3\cdot 239^3} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 239^5} - \frac{1}{7\cdot 239^7} + \ldots\right)
$$

Method $2$: 
$$
\pi = 2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1\cdot 2}{3\cdot 5} + \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7} + \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4}{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9} + \ldots\right)
$$

For each iteration method $1$ get closer to pi rather than method $2$ but the computation time for method $2$ is better. Is there a way to calculate and compare the computation time for method $1$ and $2$ ?

Comment: That's not Machin's formula!

Comment: It is his formula. I wrote the $\arctan$ function out.

Comment: Well it is now, you've gone and **corrected** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply methods, it is comfortable to keep pre-calculed values for current term:

**Method** $1$:

```
term = 1/5;
sign = 1;
x = 1;
y = 5;
value = term; (for pi/16)
for loop := 1 .. n
   sign := -sign; 
   x := x + 2;
   y := 25 * y;
   term := 1 / (x * y);
   value = value + sign * term;

value = value * 16;
```

$1$ loop: $1$ division, $0-1$ branching, $2-3$ multiplications,  $3$ simple arithmetic ops.

**Method** $2$:

```
term = 1;
x = 1;  dx = 0;
y = 1;  dy = 1;
value = term; (for pi/2)
for loop := 1 .. n
    dx = dx + 1;
    dy = dy + 2;
    x := x * dx;
    y := y * dy;
    term = term * x / y;
    value = value + term;

value = value * 2;
```

$1$ loop: $1$ division, $3$ multiplications, $3$ simple arithmetic ops.

Since division is the slowest operation, methods are **close by speed** of calculation $n$ terms (method $2$ can be a bit slower).

How fast terms are decreasing for each method?

**Method** $1$: 
$\left|\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right| = \dfrac{(2n+1) 5^{2n+1}}{(2n+3)5^{2n+3}} = \dfrac{(2n+1)}{(2n+3)25} \approx \dfrac{1}{25}$.

**Method** $2$: $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \dfrac{n}{2n+1} \approx \dfrac{1}{2}$.

So "term multiplier" $\dfrac{1}{25}$ in method $1$ is much better than $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in method $2$.

Since (for "term multipliers"  not greater than $0.5$) we can estimate error by the last term roughly, $-$

error for method $1$: $\epsilon_1(n) \sim \dfrac{1}{25^n}$;

error for method $2$: $\epsilon_2(n) \sim \dfrac{1}{2^n}$.

---

So, method $1$ is more effective (due to this factor $\dfrac{1}{25}$).

Comment: And moreover, method $1$ corresponds to alternating stuff !

Comment: Method 2 iss called the euler transformation for the Leibniz series. I am surprised if it should be slower than macin's approach.

Comment: Is it the right convergence rate after I updated my question ?

Comment: @Ole Petersen: yes, time for method 1 will be 2x slower (due to 2 terms calculation), but asymptotic behavior will remain the same: 
$$|u_n|=16\cdot \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)5^{2n+1}} - 4\cdot \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)239^{2n+1}}  \\ = \dfrac{16}{(2n+1)5^{2n+1}} \cdot \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{4} \left(\dfrac{5}{239}\right)^{2n+1}\right) \\ \sim \dfrac{16}{(2n+1)5^{2n+1}},$$
therefore 
$$\left|\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right| \sim \dfrac{(2n+1)5^{2n+1}}{(2n+3)5^{2n+3}} \sim \dfrac{1}{5^2} = \dfrac{1}{25}.$$